# Syntactic sugar forces me to use an ugly statement

Tags: ruby

```rb
def foo(bar)
  'return value'
end

foo 'bar' # => "return value"

def foo=(bar)
  'return value'
end

foo = 'bar' # => "bar"

send :foo=, 'bar' # => "return value"
```

I want `foo = 'bar'` to return `"return value"` but not to use `send` for this purpose. How can I do this?

## Update

I need a desired behavior in my gem. Here is an example:

```rb
car = Car.new
car.gear # => :first
car.next_gear # => :second
car.gear # => :second

car.gear = :fourth # => false
car.gear # => :second

car.gear = :third # => :third
car.gear # => :third
```

Comment: Any reason you can't just sidestep the assignment operator and have a regular method e.g. `def set_foo(bar)` ? Reason I suggest it is that most libraries/use of assignment expects current behaviour of returning RHS (and altering breaks contract of how assignment is supposed to work), so it should only be your code that needs alternative behaviour.

Comment: @NeilSlater, look at update to my question

Comment: Looks like inadvisable design to me. You'd be breaking with the Ruby convention for a personal style choice. What would be wrong with `car.change_gear :fourth` instead of `car.gear = :fourth`?  Your other choice would be to raise an error if someone tried to set an improper gear (arguably that would be better than expecting user to handle return value from assignemnt)

Answer (score 5):

Assignments **always** return the right hand side of an assignment.

Have a look at the [ruby documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html) for details:

> Methods that end with an equals sign indicate an assignment method.
>   For assignment methods the return value is ignored, the arguments are
>   returned instead.

Having said that, `foo = bar` also assigns to a local variable `foo` instead of using the `foo=` method. Again, this is defined in [the ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Assignment+Methods):

> When using method assignment you must always have a receiver. If you
>   do not have a receiver Ruby assumes you are assigning to a local
>   variable

You can test that by running

```
local_variables #=> []
def foo=(bar);end
foo = 42
local_variables #=> [:foo]
```

You see that the local variable `foo` was created. Better use `self.foo = 'bar'`.

To address your specific problem with your gem: Follow Neil's advice and use an extra method like `change_gear` for what you want to do. He gave you good council in his comments.

Comment: There's more to it than that, actually. (See my answer.)

Comment: @Denis have a look at my update. The 'local variable thing' is also intended behaviour.

Comment: Yes, I think it's clear to everyone answering why foo = 42 would assign the local variable, including OP. The point I'd stress is that you doesn't explain why OP needed to use `send foo=, …` instead of `self.foo =`. This has to do (per my answer) with a shortcut that Ruby is taking.

Answer (score 2):

It's a Ruby gotcha: the return value of accessor methods get ignored.

This code will make it more clear what is actually happening:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def foo(bar)
  p "called :foo w/ #{bar.inspect}"
end

def foo=(bar)
  p "called :foo= with #{bar.inspect}"
end

ret = (foo :bar1)            # calls foo(bar)
p "ret: #{ret}"              # "ret: called :foo w/ :bar1"
ret = (foo = :bar2)          # assigns a local variable foo = 'bar2'
p "ret: #{ret}"              # "ret: bar2"
ret = (send :foo=, :bar3)    # calls foo=(bar), returns what p returns
p "ret: #{ret}"              # "ret: called :foo= with :bar3"
ret = (self.foo = :bar4)     # calls foo=(bar), returns ???
p "ret: #{ret}"              # "ret: bar4"
```

Basically, the Ruby parser (in 2.1 at least) behaves as if `self.foo=` was calling an accessor method (even if it actually isn't assigning anything), and **will always return the value passed to it irrespective of what you sent it, rather than the accessor's return value**.

Demonstration:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class << self
  attr_accessor :foo

  def foo=(bar)
    p "called :foo= with #{bar.inspect}"
    @foo = :baz
  end
end

ret = (self.foo = :bar)
p "ret: #{ret} vs @foo: #{@foo.inspect}"
```

Outputs:

```
"called :foo= with :bar"
"ret: bar vs @foo: :baz"
```

Edit: hat @tessi for the [reference](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html):

> Methods that end with an equals sign indicate an assignment method. For assignment methods the return value is ignored, the arguments are returned instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason why it's failing is that local variable names take precedence over method names when they are defined.

So you need to use `send` so that `self` knows it's looking for a method instead of a variable.

Comment: Indeed, this is not the whole answer, but not wrong either. You have to have a receiver to make ruby call the `foo=` method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
 self.foo = 'bar'
```

Comment: `self.foo = 'bar'` returns `'bar'` for me on ruby 2.0

Comment: @tessi: indeed, but I think OP is running into a Ruby bug or gotcha. `self.foo` *should* call `foo=`. And sure enough it does if you define an `attr_accessor`.